# How to automate Swing application using Swing library (or) Remote Swing Library

Tags: swing, intellij-idea, robotframework, ui-automation, jython

I need to automate jnlp application. Currently i chose swing library with robot framework for automation. I need help in configuring intellij with libraries/jars. I tried many methods, but library is not importing. But Remote swing library is importing, Swing library not importing.

*** Settings ***
Library SwingLibrary

This is my code for import.
I downloaded jython jar.

kindly help to set all the requirements for automation.

Comment: swing library needs Jython -- new robot framework doesnt work on Jython anymore.

Comment: Your best bet of automating Swing apps is going to be Sikuli. Swing tooling for test automation is really old and haven't been maintained in a Long Time.

Comment: Sikuli is image based right ? We doesn't required like xpath to locate the elements in sikuli. But in future if we change any option in UI means again we need to alter the test cases right ? If we automate using element locators like xpath in selenium means, no need to alter much in test cases in future.

what is your idea about this ?